# Error with drawing point on QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I'm trying to draw on `QLabel` in `Qt` like this:

paintscene.h:

```
class PaintScene : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PaintScene(QWidget* parent = NULL);

    QVector<QLabel*> _layers;
    QColor _color;
    int _width;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private slots:
    void updateWidth();
};
```

paintscene.cpp:

```
PaintScene::PaintScene(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    _width = 10;
    _color = Qt::red;
    QLabel* inital = new QLabel(this);
    inital->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : white; }");
    _layers.push_back(inital);

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
    layout->addWidget(inital, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    this->setLayout(layout);
}

void PaintScene::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QImage tmp = _layers.back()->pixmap()->toImage();
    QPainter painter(&tmp);
    QPen paintpen(_color);
    paintpen.setWidth(_width);
    painter.setPen(paintpen);
    painter.drawPoint(event->x(), event->y());
    _layers.back()->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(tmp));
}
```

The list is needed because I want to implement the work with layers (`QLabel` - a separate layer).

However, I get an error, the program terminates. The error occurs on the line `QImage tmp = _layers.back()->pixmap()->toImage();`.

What makes this happen? How can this be fixed? Maybe for a layer to use something different, not `QLabel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Jeremy Friesner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131930/jeremy-friesner) is right about the reason for the error, not having a QPixmap this will be null, in my answer I will show a possible solution

```
void PaintScene::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QLabel *label = _layers.back();
    const QPixmap *pix= label->pixmap();
    QPixmap pixmap;
    if(pix)
        pixmap =  *pix;
    else{
        pixmap = QPixmap(label->size());
        pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    }
    QPainter painter(&pixmap);
    QPen paintpen(_color);
    paintpen.setWidth(_width);
    painter.setPen(paintpen);
    painter.drawPoint(event->pos());
    painter.end();
    label->setPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) for `QLabel::pixmap()`:

```
This property holds the label's pixmap
If no pixmap has been set this will return 0.
```

... so when you do this:

```
QImage tmp = _layers.back()->pixmap()->toImage();
```

`pixmap()` is returning NULL (because the QLabel has never had any QPixmap set on it yet), and then you try to dereference that NULL pointer to call `toImage()` on it, hence the crash.

To avoid crashing, don't try to create a QImage from a NULL QPixmap pointer.

I suspect you wanted to be calling `grab()` instead of `pixmap()` -- `grab()` will create a QPixmap for you that contains the visual appearance of the QLabel.  However, an even better approach would be to avoid messing about with `QPixmaps` at all; instead, make your own subclass of the `QLabel` class, and override its `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` method to first call up to `QLabel::paintEvent(e)` and then use a QPainter to draw the additional point afterwards.  That will be easier to implement and also more efficient at runtime.